# Event after form is fully loaded?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to do an event after `Form_Load` event.

What is the event of "form fully loaded"?

Answer (score 34):

You are looking for the event Form.Shown().

[See the references on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx)

This is the last event in the event chain when you open a form as [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)
The Form 'Load' event is raised before the form is visible, the form 'Shown' event is raised when the form is visible. (and all controls too)

Also, remember to avoid calls to MessageBox inside the form 'Load' event, this disrupts the normal flow of events.

Answer (score 13):

You likely want to use [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx).  This is the last event raised during the initial display of the form.

For details, see [Order of Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx).  It details which events are raised, and in which order.